# How to perform pagination in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

i need pagination concept to display 15 records.
 this is my jsp file.

```
<%
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
%>
<%!String s;
int i;%>
<%
al = op.getCountry();
%>
<jsp:scriptlet>
session.setAttribute( "EmpList", al);
</jsp:scriptlet>
<display:table id="domList" pagesize="10" name="sessionScope.EmpList"> 
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="dataTable">

<tr bgcolor="#57e3ff">
    <td><strong>Country</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Action</strong></td>
</tr>
<% int a = 0, i = 0;
    while (i < al.size()) {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                                                                                s = "#f3f4f4";
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                s = "#ebebec";
                                                                            }%>

<tr bgcolor="<%=s%>">
    <td><display:column  value="<%=al.get(i)%>" />  </td>
    <td align="center"><div id='basic-modal-cdel'>
            <a href='#' id="<%=al.get(i)%>" onclick="return del();"
               class='basic-cdel'><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/delete.png"
                                    alt="Delete" title="Delete" border="0" /></a>
        </div></td>
    <td align="center"><div id='basic-modal-country'>
            <a href='#' id="<%=al.get(i)%>" class='basic-country'
               onclick="validatedit()"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/edit-icon.png"
                                         alt="Update" title="Update" border="0" /></a>
        </div></td>
</tr>

<%
        i++;
        a++;
    }

%>
```

please help me iam newbie in pagination. i want to show only 10 records per page. i tried it through display tag but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

The **[Display Tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/)** library is an open source library which provides pagination  functionality while still being easy to use.

You can set your records in request scope from your servlet class.

```
request.setAttribute( "test", new TestList(10, false) );
```

and Then you can use display tag library to display it with pagination.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>


<display:table name="test" pagesize="15" >
  <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
  <display:column property="name" />
  <display:column property="email" />
  <display:column property="status" />
  <display:column property="description" title="Comments"/>
</display:table>
```

You can find it's basic tutorials [here](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_basic.html).

---

Updated:

You need not to use `<table>, <tr>, <td>` tag only `<display:table> and <display:column>` is enough.
You can directly use fields from EmpList inside property tag of `<display:column>`.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.javaworkspace.com/displayTags.do).

Comment: hi Ankur thnks for rply. i just go through its tutorial. however, that is not enough for me for sure. m going to edit my post please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the [Display tag library](http://www.displaytag.org). It provides paging capability for your JSP page. You just need to pass a list of objects to this taglib and it will add pagination to your page. It also support other functionality such as sorting, grouping, export, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Display Tag Library` and it does everything by fly. Just pass the list into the display:table property and display tag will take care of the rest. You can also use EL with it. It is easy to use and also maintainable.