# How to limit the amount of rows in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Really have no idea were to start, been researching for such a long time and this seems my last option. I have a table which is connected to a database.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>

</tr>

<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_code}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_author}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_name}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_description}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_price}"/></td>
<td> <a href="jsporder.jsp?itemCode=${row.item_code}">Buy! </a> </td>
<td> <img src="<c:url value = "${row.item_image_loc}"/>" height="50" style="border:none; background:none; overflow:none; width:35%" alt="Connection to mySQL for pictures"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

So for example the table will look like this.

Code   Author Name Description Price

12....J.K....Potter.Wizard...£2.12...Buy!....(image)

etc (There will be 10+ more books).

What I want to do is make a java script function form were I input the amount of books i want to appear on the table.

So for example if I input 2 only the first 2 books will be displayed on the database.

Comment: I think you're looking for pagination. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939431/how-to-perform-pagination-in-jsp

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks very much for your reply. I've looked at many examples but I still does not work with my code. How can I make a user input so they can control how many rows are outputted?